# Is there something wrong with the circuit below?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

I have built a 2 bit counter, so it normally counts from 0 to 3, but I want it to count up to 2. I have added a hex display and I can see 3 displayed there. The circuit is below:

[image]

Comment: What do you want to happen if your counter is at 2 and you clock it?

Comment: I want it to go back to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the flops to be Synchronous, so your reset signal is generated  when both Q outputs  are 1 and both flops will be reset in the next  clock cycle. In other words you have to generate reset when you have the value 10. So add a negation to the input of AND gate coming from U1A and it should work..

Comment: No need to *add* a negation, just connect it to the \$\overline{Q}\$.